# Range of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity

If $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z_0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function with an essential singularity at $z_0$, is there any **elementary** reason why there exists at least **one** complex value that the function takes infinitely often in any neighbourhood of $z_0$? The non-elementary reason is Picard's Theorem.

Comment: an entire function $g(z)$ having finitely many zeros can be written $g(z) = e^{h(z)}P(z)$ (where $P(z)$ is a polynomial and $h(z)$ is entire). In the same way, if $g(z)$ takes the value $a \ne 0$ only finitely often then $g(z)-a = e^{h_2(z)} P_2(z)$, and $e^{h(z)} P(z) = e^{h_2(z)} P_2(z)-a$ should lead to a contradiction